# How to stop scripts execution on the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a random internet page opened in my Chrome. I'm opening it with enabled javascript as I need some scripts to be executed.

Than from some moment I want to stop script execution, so no any timers or event handlers should be run. Of couse using an infinite loop is not ok as I want the page to be responsive.

How can I achive that?

Following code partially does what I need

```
document.body.outerHTML = document.body.outerHTML
for(t=setTimeout(()=>{}); t; --t) clearTimeout(t)
```

but:

1. Event listeners on `document` and ajax callbacks will survive
2. This causes parsing html, so some invalid markup can be changed by parsing

Also I hope there is some way to do it via devtools without actually interacting with page's code.

PS: If I need to use other browser, that's ok.

Comment: have u tried to set a breakpoint on your first line of javascript?

Comment: @Sysix, try to use scroll on the page while using breakpoint.

Comment: hm in chrome its weard.. I use Firefox Developer Edition, there I can easily scroll :)

Comment: @Sysix, ok, you can scroll in FF. But no hover styles and no ability to set focus or to type the text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can enable/disable JavaScript on the page at any point using the command menu in DevTools. You can access this menu by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux).

Start typing `Disable JavaScript` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to disable script execution.

In the following example, I ran an asynchronous timer to log an incremental count every 500ms. Upon disabling JavaScript, the execution was paused and nothing else logged to the console.

[image: Disable]

I later re-enabled JavaScript by typing 'Enable JavaScript` and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Upon doing this, the execution continued and the timer continued where it left off.

[image: Paused]

**Note:** Any synchronous code still running when you try to disable JavaScript won't be killed. It will finish and then further execution will be disabled.

Comment: For further control, I suppose you could set a breakpoint on the exact line of code where you want to "stop script execution", and then disable JS while paused. I haven't tried it though, so can't be sure there aren't any side effects.

Comment: Great! By some reason I thought it'll work after page reload.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Gideon Pyzer:

`Shift-Ctrl-I` - wait for devTools to open,
then `Shift-Ctrl-P` - if you don't wait: print dialog will open...
then -see Gideon Pyzer's answer-.